# Moving PerspectiveCamera in the direction it is facing in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, viewport3d

I am currently working in a wpf application which has a `Viewport3D` camera.
And I am creating a 3D walkthrough module. 
I want my `PerspectiveCamera` to move based on the direction the it is facing after the Look Directions has changed.
I am using my keyboard to control the movement, for example:
`NUMPAD8`: move forward
`NUMPAD2`: move backward
`NUMPAD4`: rotate left
`NUMPAD6`: rotate right

This method below is to detect keyboard event:

```
 private void button20_KeyDown(Object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.NumPad6)
        {
            Rotate(1);
        }
        else if (e.Key == Key.NumPad4)
        {
            Rotate(-1);
        }
        else if (e.Key == Key.NumPad8)
        {
            Move(-10);
        }
        else if (e.Key == Key.NumPad2)
        {
            Move(10);
        }
    }
```

This is to calculate rotation:

```
public void Rotate(double d)
    {
        double u = 0.05;
        double angleD = u * d;
        PerspectiveCamera camera = (PerspectiveCamera)Viewport3D.Camera;
        Vector3D lookDirection = camera.LookDirection;
        double L = lookDirection.Length;
        double D = 2 * L * Math.Sin(angleD / 2);
        double m = Math.Sqrt(lookDirection.X * lookDirection.X + lookDirection.Y * lookDirection.Y);
        double angleA = 2 * Math.Asin(D / (2 * m));
        double x = lookDirection.X;
        double y = lookDirection.Y;
        double angleB = Math.Atan2(y, x);
        double angleG = angleB - angleA;
        double newx = m * Math.Cos(angleG);
        double newy = m * Math.Sin(angleG);
        Vector3D NewlookDirection = new Vector3D(newx, newy, lookDirection.Z);
        camera.LookDirection = NewlookDirection;

    }
```

This is to calculate the camera movement:

```
public void Move(double d)
    {
        double u = 0.05;
        PerspectiveCamera camera = (PerspectiveCamera)Viewport3D.Camera;
        Vector3D lookDirection = camera.LookDirection;
        Point3D position = camera.Position;
        //Point3D NewPosition = new Point3D();
        position.Y += d;
        //NewPosition.X = position.X + u * lookDirection.X * d;
        //NewPosition.Y = position.Y + u * lookDirection.Y * d;
        //NewPosition.Z = position.Z + u * lookDirection.Z * d;
        //camera.Position = NewPosition;
        camera.Position = position;
    }
```

The rotation calculation works perfect but the movement seems not working good as it moves the camera based on the camera position instead of the facing direction after the rotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commented out code looks more or less right... you didn't say what was wrong with it. Have you tried to normalize the lookDirection vector? Normalizing a vector makes it have a magnitude (length) of 1.

```
public void Move(double d)
{
    double u = 0.05;
    PerspectiveCamera camera = (PerspectiveCamera)Viewport3D.Camera;
    Vector3D lookDirection = camera.LookDirection;
    Point3D position = camera.Position;

    lookDirection.Normalize();
    position = position + u * lookDirection * d;

    camera.Position = position;
}
```

UPDATE:

```
private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.NumPad6)
    {
        Rotate(10);
    }
    else if (e.Key == Key.NumPad4)
    {
        Rotate(-10);
    }
    else if (e.Key == Key.NumPad8)
    {
        Move(-10);
    }
    else if (e.Key == Key.NumPad2)
    {
        Move(10);
    }
    else if (e.Key == Key.PageUp)
    {
        RotateVertical(10);
    }
    else if (e.Key == Key.PageDown)
    {
        RotateVertical(-10);
    }
}
public void Rotate(double d)
{
    double u = 0.05;
    double angleD = u * d;
    PerspectiveCamera camera = (PerspectiveCamera)Viewport3D.Camera;
    Vector3D lookDirection = camera.LookDirection;

    var m = new Matrix3D();
    m.Rotate(new Quaternion(camera.UpDirection, -angleD)); // Rotate about the camera's up direction to look left/right
    camera.LookDirection = m.Transform(camera.LookDirection);
}

public void RotateVertical(double d)
{
    double u = 0.05;
    double angleD = u * d;
    PerspectiveCamera camera = (PerspectiveCamera)Viewport3D.Camera;
    Vector3D lookDirection = camera.LookDirection;

    // Cross Product gets a vector that is perpendicular to the passed in vectors (order does matter, reverse the order and the vector will point in the reverse direction)
    var cp = Vector3D.CrossProduct(camera.UpDirection, lookDirection);
    cp.Normalize();

    var m = new Matrix3D();
    m.Rotate(new Quaternion(cp, -angleD)); // Rotate about the vector from the cross product
    camera.LookDirection = m.Transform(camera.LookDirection);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution but your solution is something similar with the commented out code.   
The commented out part is something like zooming in and out to the facing direction. For example if I keep zooming in, it eventually will phase through the floor.
What I want is something like a immersive walkthrough. Like a first perspective of the user view in the 3D environment. More simple words, the user is like walking in the 3D environment.

Comment: Wpf does just the rendering. You need to build a collision engine or use an existing one like Bullet Physics. It has a c# wrapper, BulletSharp - https://andrestraks.github.io/BulletSharp/

Comment: Thank you. Could you explain the code in the rotation part? Because I got this code from the internet and I not really understand what is it doing exactly. Just a briefly explain is necessary. Appreciate much.

Comment: Uhhh... no. It looks like it is manually running though some equations (rotation equations no doubt). I would suggest you implement that code yourself if you want to really understand it. Start with some 3d rotation equations. I've updated my answer to include another way to rotate the camera using Matrix3D (a wpf class). I also added a RotateVertical method the rotates the camera up/down (instead of left/right).